# Convert Base64 Image File URI to a File Object

Tags: javascript, angular, file, ionic-framework, base64

I have to send the `File` object as payload to the backend API. How can I convert a Base64 Image File URI to a File object format as mentioned below? I tried to look up for other solutions but those are with Blob to file conversion or base64 data url conversion. Could anyone please help?

**Base64 Image File URL**

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/cache/1586842420784.jpg
```

This needs to be converted to

**File Object**

```
File {
   lastModified: 1582829787565
   lastModifiedDate: Thu Feb 27 2020 10:56:27 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) {}
   name: "TestImageAM.png"
   size: 186278
   type: "image/png"
   webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Comment: is `data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/cache/1586842420784.jpg` even a thing? a data URI, encoded in base64 is the raw data of a thing (image in this case) encoded in base64 - not the path of an actual file

Comment: Yes it is, I get that from this plugin in Ionic `this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      (imageData) => {}` Here, imageData is what I have posted, the Base64 File Image URI

Comment: *the Base64 File Image URI* - huh? are you saying `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/cache/1586842420784.jpg` is base64? `.` and `:` are not part of base64, and a file with `.jpg` extension is unlikely to contain base64 encoded data - so, from start to finish, you are not making sense

Comment: Just read the documentation for that getPicture function ... *imageData is either a base64 encoded string **OR** a file URI* ... now, a base64 encoded string would be like `ABCDEFG`, i.e. a series of characters, `A-Z`,`a-z`,`0-9`,`+`,`/` ... whereas, a file URI would be like `file:///some/path/filename.jpg` .... you've confused yourself and added a data URI prefix to a file URI

Comment: In the documentation, the `let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;` is if imageData is a base64 string - the fact that you end up with `data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///...` is because your code is adding that prefix when it doesn't need to for a file URI

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the best option would be converting the base64 image string to a blob like this

```
    fetch(base64ImageString)
    .then((res) => res.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      console.log(blob);
    });
```

Which logs the blob object to the console like below

```
Blob {size: 20832, type: "image/jpeg"}
```

And then upload the image using formData which supports uploading image files in blob format like this.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('my_image', blob);
```

You can get more information regarding how to upload images using formData from the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do is, pass the Base64 Image URI to [JavaScript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) `File` constructor and that should give you the File object in your required format.

```
fileURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/cache/1586842420784.jpg'
const file = new File(fileURI, 'anyname.jpg')
console.log('File Object', file)
```

Comment: But it gives me the File Object in this format having all the values null
`{"name":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.slicktalks/cache/1586844010984.jpg","localURL":"filename.png","type":null,"lastModified":null,"lastModifiedDate":null,"size":0,"start":0,"end":0}`